# How to automatically delete rows which contain a cell with a value less that a certain number

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering whether anyone will be able to help me with an excel query:

I'm trying to find a way to delete all rows which contains a number less than 1000 in column "G" (the data begins at: column G, row 20)

From what i understand, macros seem to be the most useful function but i'm a complete amateur with it

Any help on this would be most appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You can use FilterOption to filter out data which is less than than 1000 and then manually delete the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub RowKiller()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, rr As Range
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 20 Step -1
        Set rr = Cells(i, "G")
        If rr.Value < 1000 Then
            rr.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```